# snowflake ntile of engagement rate over month

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, percentile

I'm trying to write a query that ranks a customer's engagement rate by decile within a month, against all other customers.

I tried:

```
        ntile(10) over (partition by rec_month order by engagement_rate) as decile
```

but I don't think that is getting me what I need. It appears to just be splitting the vhosts up into 10 equally sized groups. I want percentiles.

I also tried:

```
        ntile(10) over (partition by rec_month, vhost order by engagement_rate) as decile
```

But that is only calculating it within customer (vhost) within the month.

How do I calculate the engagement_rate decile against all other customers (Vhosts) within the month?

Comment: What do you mean:  "I want percentiles"?  The first query seems to be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

At first I suspect you a rank function, like [DENSE_RANK](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/dense_rank.html) or [RANK](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/rank.html) (which is sparse, the on I'd use), and then turn that to a percentage by dividing by the count(*) and then truncating into deciles by `(trunc(V/10)*10)`, but then I suspect you might want the output of the [PERCENT_RANK](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/percent_rank.html) function, but the snowflake documentation example is not as clarifying as I would hope, to know it solves your problem.

```
select column1,
   column2,
   round(percent_rank() over (order by column2),3) as p_rank,
   trunc(p_rank*10)*10 as decile
from values ('a',1),('b',2),('c',3),('d',4),('e',5),('f',6),('g',7);
```

gives

```
COLUMN1  COLUMN2   P_RANK      DECILE
a        1         0           0
b        2         0.167       10
c        3         0.333       30
d        4         0.5         50
e        5         0.667       60
f        6         0.833       80
g        7         1           100
```

but maybe you want to use ntile instead of the truncating of the percentage. The round is just there to make the answers above less verbose.